# Cannot launch Chrome or Firefox Driver with StartWebSession[]

Tags: web-access, webtools, webdriver

The Mathematica 12 in my computer cannot launch Chrome or Firefox session correctly. The first error message is

```
    Import::jsonhintposandchar: An error occurred near character 'h', at line 1:3
```

I guess that the Mathematica cannot find my Firefox and geckodriver so I tried to add the install directory to the $Path of Mathematica but found it useless. The StartWebSession[] shows no option for me to assign particular external executable program for web-driver.\

I have tried to remove the paclet however it also seems have no effect.

OS: Windows10 Version 1909

MMA: version 12.0

Comment: Have you tried using [StartWebSession](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StartWebSession.html)?

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi Sorry for that typo. I am exactly using the StartWebSession in mma12